# The imagewebp function fails without generating any errors

Tags: php, gd

I want to convert a folder of jpeg images to webp format in another folder. I'm using the imagewebp function in the GD library. The code just halts when the function is called. Although the file is actually created it is of zero length. No errors are thrown.

> gd_info shows version 2.1 with WebP support as 1.
>
> php version 5.6

Everything works if I change to `imagepng()` so the library is installed and working.

I've tried on individual small images in case it was a memory issue but still has the same problem.

Also tried imagecreatefromjpeg instead of imagecreatefromstring but same.

Removed the quality filter to default (eg omitted the 65) but the same effect.

I also tried outputting a single file directly to the browser. This works with imagepng, but I get a 404 error with imagewebp

```
$jpgfiles = glob ('jpegs/*.jpg');
echo "<p>" . sizeof( $jpgfiles ) . " files found. </p>"; // Shows 7 files   
foreach($jpgfiles as $j) {
    echo "<p>Found $j</p>"; // Shows first found file
    $filename = substr( $j, 6, -4) . '.webp'; // Keep the same filename but change extension
    echo "<p>$filename</p>";
    $jpgimage = imagecreatefromstring( file_get_contents( $j ) );
    if( !$jpgimage ) die ("Failed on imagecreatefromstring");

   if( $webpimage = imagewebp( $jpgimage, 'webps/' . $filename, 65 )) echo "$filename created"; // This is never echo'd
   else die ("Failed on imagewebp"); // Doesn't die either
   imagedestroy ( $jpgimage );

}
```

I expected the images to be created but program execution stops. The error log does not contain any information. The die command is never invoked. The webp file is created but is of zero length.

Comment: So, uh, is error_reporting really on? How about creating/saving an empty image for testing? `strace php -r 'imagewebp(imagecreatetruecolor(10,10));'`

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

imagewebp(imagecreatetruecolor(10,10), 'stack.webp'); 

When ran came up with a 404 error, the stack.webp file is created but zero length and the error.log file is empty.

Comment: Testing on the commandline might be more productive than watching the 404 (apache or fpm log, btw, when a process crashes).

Comment: I'm not familiar with running from the command line, but I tried this and got a zillion lines of text. The final two lines were
+++ killed by SIGABRT +++
Aborted

Comment: The Apache error log has *** stack smashing detected ***: /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-cgi terminated

Comment: Well, in conclusion: you have an obscure stack overflow in libgd, and are using an ancient PHP setup.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I can't upgrade PHP at this time but surely the function should work? I guessed its obscure as there doesn't seem to be any reference to anybody suffering from anything similar. I'll just have to manually change the images with gimp.